# fetched data getting updated

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to give permission to different users based on their roles. The permissions are **fetch, add, delete, edit etc**. When i give only certain permission to a user like for example, if I give only **add and delete** for user1 then while creating the next user and then while giving permission only **add and delete** are available, the other permissions are not avaliable. How do i resolve this ? I want a new group id for each roles permission. I tried coding it below, but it doesn't seem to work.

> **service.ts**

```
add_permission(data){
var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Token ' + 
localStorage.getItem('usertoken'));

var options =  {
  headers: headers
};
return this.httpClient.post('/api/auth/permission_list/',data, 
options)
 }
```

> **component.ts**

```
id :number;
dropdown_data:any = [];
checkedList = [];
permissionList:any = [];
perms:any = [];
permission_data:any = [];


onChange(email:string, checked: boolean) {
if(checked) {
this.perms.push(this.permission_data.permission_list)
} 
}

ngOnInit(): void{

//get permission 

  this.Authentication.get_permissions().subscribe(res =>{
    this.permissionList = res;
    console.log(res);

    for(let val of this.permissionList){ 
      this.dropdown_data = val.permission_list
      this.id = val.group_id
    }    
  })

}

//getting values of selected check box

onCheckboxChange(val, event) {
if(event.target.checked) {
this.checkedList.push(val);
console.log(this.checkedList);
} else {
for(var i=0 ; i < this.dropdown_data.length; i++) {
  if(this.checkedList[i] == val){
    this.checkedList.splice(i,1);
  }
}
}
}

// add permission

addPermission(){
let permissions = {};
permissions['group_id'] = this.id
permissions['permission_list']= this.checkedList;
console.log(permissions)

this.Authentication.add_permission(permissions).subscribe(res => {
  console.log('added')
},
err =>{
console.log('error');
})
}
```

> **component.html**

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <table class="table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th scope="col">Permissions</th>
           <th scope="col">Select/Unselect</th>    
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody *ngFor="let val of dropdown_data" >
          <tr>

            <td>{{val}}</td>
              <td><label class="container-1">
                <input type="checkbox"  value="{{val}}" (change)="onCheckboxChange(val,$event)" >
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label></td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
          <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary pull-right" (click)="addPermission()">Submit</button>
         </div>
```

Comment: Hi. Can you post the result of this log in your code `console.log(res);` in the `ngOnInit()` function?

Comment: It is giving group_id:2 and permission_list:Array(2)  0:"Add user" 1:"Delete user". The thing is instead of doing post request it is actually doing put request. Like its getting updated and not creating a new group_id and permission list.